# Not getting any output of a query when hosted site on IIS server but it is running fine on windows powershell

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

How can this problem can be solved and there is permission granted to the account used to host the site on IIS server still not getting the query the query is for finding something in AD directory

Comment: Are you referring to LDAP queries? Since running a query via PowerShell console under your account and via IIS web app under the pool identity differs too much, what you described isn't surprising. There are quite a few other well known issues in my blog post, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: What did you query and didn't get any query output? And what are you running on Windows powershell? Please edit your question to describe it in detail.

Comment: I wanted to run ad query to fetch the specefic user detail that query was running fine in powershell but not on iis server

Comment: Based on your description, maybe you are using some function or code in your website to try to retrieve data from AD, but you are unable to get the required output on the IIS server. But it works fine in Windows PowerShell.

Even if they have granted the appropriate permissions to the account hosting the site on the IIS server, there may be a lack of specific permissions required to perform AD queries.

This may require adding the application pool identity to the appropriate AD group so that the IIS application pool's identity has the necessary permissions to perform AD queries.